Bridging faces completely doesn't work
For some context, Im modelling for Roblox so the triangle count has to be kept lower than 10,000. I also do need to make it optimized so keeping it as low on the triangle count is the best case scenario. I also dont consider myself particularly great at blender but Im decent
My problem is when I use the bridge faces tool between 2 cylinders, both the same size and have the same amount of edges, but when using the tool, the bridge between the two cylinders goes really weird and sticks out like crazy. Changing the smoothness or any of those settings doesnt do anything. Please check the image to see the error.
Its extremely inconsistent and sometimes it works perfectly fine. I just need help on why this is happening.


If @Leander is right, I would further recommend, whatever the tutorials say.. when modelling, never scale in Object Mode, always scale in Edit Mode.

Apply the scale of your object.
Object Mode: CtrlA >Scale

Non uniform scale affects edit mode operations.

